# Convert generically typed argument lambda delegate to object

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, delegates

I have the following method:

```
void Foo<T1>(Func<T1, Exception> exceptionFunc)
{
   // Following line error: "Cannot convert from 'object' to 'T1'
   Func<object, Exception> exF = (e) => exceptionFunc(e);
   Foo2(exF);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to cast the `Func`'s generic argument `T1` to an `object` which is required by `Foo2()`, any ideas of how to do this successfully?

Comment: `Func<object, Exception> exF = (e) => exceptionFunc((T1)e);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the object to T1:

```
void Foo<T1>(Func<T1, Exception> exceptionFunc)
{
    // Following line error: "Cannot convert from 'object' to 'T1'
    Func<object, Exception> exF = obj => exceptionFunc((T1)obj);
    Foo2(exF);
}
```

Note: That will throw an invalid cast exception at runtime if the object is not compatible to T1.

Comment: I tried `Func<object, Exception> exF = obj => exceptionFunc((object)obj);` earlier which was the wrong cast of course. Thanks.